# Object Reference Not set to an instance error after deploying the code

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, nullreferenceexception

I am using asp.net GridView for displaying data, I have 9 columns coming from Database,from which I have to hide last two columns and records of those. I am using GridView RowDatabound event for hiding the columns and records.
Its working fine when I am running my application from VS, even when I publish it on local IIS, it is working fine, but when I deployed it live, its giving following exception:

Object reference not set to an instance

I am using same database for both publishes
Here's my code

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
                                </asp:GridView>




        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
            {

                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[7].Visible = false;
                GridView1.HeaderRow.Cells[8].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[7].Visible = false;
                e.Row.Cells[8].Visible = false;               
            }
        }
```

Databinding is done with DataTable

```
     var data = MyClass.GetHistory();//it returns DataTable
     GridView1.DataSource = data;
     GridView1.DataBind();
```

Comment: On which line exactly? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it

Comment: Can you show us `MyClass.GetHistory();`?

Comment: Data coming from datasource may not be the same if you are connecting to a different server when you publish it.

Comment: @SonerGönül on RowDatabound event

Comment: Most probably your application cannot connect to the DB on the deployment server.

Comment: Both databases are same

Comment: May be an issue with different data sets in local and production? That could be a reason for exceptions in the prod server, when it is working fine locally in IIS

Comment: @LakshmiNarayanan both databases are same, I am checking with same user login

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am correct, you are trying to hide columns 7 and 8, then do it after you bound the `datasource` as,

```
GridView1.Columns[7].Visible = false;
GridView1.Columns[8].Visible = false;
```